# Can an Alchemist with Infused Extract hand them out before combat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, alchemist

Inspired by [Who can be the target of an infused extract?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116694/who-can-be-the-target-of-an-infused-extract).

Supposing an Alchemist has created their Extracts per the [Alchemy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Alchemist/#TOC-Alchemy-Su-) class feature and the [Infusion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Alchemist/discoveries/paizo-alchemist-discoveries/infusion) Discovery, would they then be able to physically hand them out at the beginning of each morning to whom they think would need the extract(s) the most, allowing other people to then use the Extracts, regardless of if the Alchemist is even nearby? Or does the Alchemist still need to 'deliver' the Extracts to use them?

Comment: I’m voting to close this as unclear what you’re asking, because I do not understand where the confusion lies. The discovery says that the extract no longer needs to remain in the alchemist’s possession, and that anyone can drink it. What else needs to be said? What part of that is confusing or makes you suspect that it *doesn’t* work the way it says it does?

Comment: Define "deliver" the extracts? A creature gains the benefit of the extract the moment they drink it.

Comment: I guess my question is more about action economy. I wasn't sure if they could be distributed ahead of time or if the Alchemist needed to spend his action(s) in combat to activate the Extract for someone else. Or if it's literally a potion-like draught anyone can use at that point.

Comment: @GreedyRadish 
See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comment was removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes.

Sharing extracts is the main benefit of the infusion discovery. However, it still follows all the usual rules for extracts.